# Logstash availability when elasticsearch dies/can't write to disk

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, rsyslog

I have rsyslog forwarding logs to logstash via TCP. If logstash is not available rsyslog will build up queues.

In the event that logstash is available, but elasticsearch is dead or for some reason cannot write to the file system.

Is there a way for logstash to reject further TCP messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [life of an event description](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/life-of-an-event):

> An output can fail or have problems because of some downstream cause, such as full disk, permissions problems, temporary network failures, or service outages. Most outputs should keep retrying to ship any events that were involved in the failure.
>
> If an output is failing, the output thread will wait until this output is healthy again and able to successfully send the message. Therefore, the output queue will stop being read from by this output and will eventually fill up with events and block new events from being written to this queue.
>
> A full output queue means filters will block trying to write to the output queue. Because filters will be stuck, blocked writing to the output queue, they will stop reading from the filter queue which will eventually cause the filter queue (input -> filter) to fill up.
>
> A full filter queue will cause inputs to block when writing to the filters. This will cause each input to block, causing each input to stop processing new data from wherever that input is getting new events.

This means that if the elasticsearch output starts to fail then the entire pipeline will be blocked which is what you want in your case. Are you seeing something different?